# Was it a King or a Queen or neither?

Tags: code-golf

## Input

A calendar year from 927 to 2022.

## Output

You can use any three distinguishable outputs.  As an example,

“K” (short for King)

or

“Q” (short for Queen)

depending on which of the two England had in that year.  If there was both a King and Queen in that year you can output either.

If there was no King or Queen for the whole of that year, your code must output something that is not one of those two messages.

## Dates

Kings: 927-1553, 1603-1649, 1660-1702, 1714-1837, 1901-1952, 2022

Queens: 1553-1603, 1689-1694, 1702-1714, 1837-1901, 1952-2022

Neither: 1650-1659

Comment: For those wondering "Why 927?" (instead of 886 or 1066), that's the year that Æthelstan officially became king of "the English" instead of "the Anglo-Saxons".

Answer (score 42):

## [Squire](https://github.com/sampersand/squire), 194 characters

```php
d=tally(inquire())i=\(d,s,e)=>s<=d&&d<=e;o=;if i(d,MDCL,MDCLIX){o= }alas if i(d,MCMLII,MMXXII)||i(d,MDCCCXXXVII,MCMI)||i(d,MDCCII,MDCCXIV)||i(d,MDLIII,MDCIII){o=}proclaim(o)
```

This contest doth be marvelously suited for ye medieval-inspired parlance, [Squire](https://github.com/sampersand/squire). Whilst Squire doth hath a veritable cornucopia of features, lamentably suitability for golfing doth be nary amongst them.

Squire only has roman numeral literals, as well as some fairly length constructs (e.g. `inquire`, `tally`, `proclaim`), so it's not as short as other languages. On the plus side, squire has bare words—however only when the strings are comprised entirely exclusively of the unicode fraktur characters or whitespace.

Unfortunately, [the interpreter](https://github.com/sampersand/squire) is not able to fit onto TIO or anything else, so if you want to test it you'll need to build locally...

Ungolfed, the program is:

```
N.B. Journeys are functions, and you get a reward for returning from them.
journey in(date, start, end) {
    reward start <= date && date <= end
}

N.B. `tally` converts to a number, `inquire` reads from stdin. 
N.B. In addition to roman numerals, `tally` also reads arabic ones too.
date = tally(inquire())

N.B. Using the fraktur literals, set the default value for `whom`.
N.B. This is sugar for "King".
whom = ; N.B. The `;` is needed here because the parser is bad lol

N.B. Check to see if the date is within Cromwell's time.
if in(date, MDCL, MDCLIX) { 
    whom =  
} alas if
    in(date, MCMLII, MMXXII)
    || in(date, MDCCCXXXVII, MCMI)
    || in(date, MDCCII, MDCCXIV)
    || in(date, MDLIII, MDCIII)
{
    whom = 
}

N.B. The printing press wasn't around way back when. So instead we have
N.B. the town crier proclaim our outputs.
proclaim("The {whom} reigned during the year {date}")
```

Comment: Definitely a very suitable answer!

Comment: Surely that "is" should also be "doth be", and maybe change "the" to "ye" while you're at it?

Comment: Trying to build Squire on WSL gives: `fatal error: ffi/ffi.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: I get the same error in a Docker container, even with `apt-get install libffi-dev`.

Comment: @Steffan yeah, squire's codebase is an absolute dumpster fire of portability, and I got other priorities over it (eg knight 2.0 :-p) If that's the only issue, then  you can straight-up comment out that import in `envoy.c`. (envoy waas my idea for FFI functionality, but i never ended up finishing it)

Comment: @Neil I like those suggestions!

Comment: @Neil  As I understand it, "ye" is actually a pronoun form.  The use of it as "the" is a french misreading of the word spelled Þe.  Þ (thorn) is one of the lost English letters, pronounced as soft "th.

Comment: "Doth hath" -> "doth have" (or just "hath," of course).

Comment: @DavidG. Yeah, i've heard that too. But that's all the more reason to use it—it's not actually old english sounding :-P

Answer (score 21):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 50 bytes

Returns \$0\$ for Queen, \$1\$ for King, or \$2\$ for neither.

This code includes some unprintable characters.

```javascript
y=>2132%Buffer(`2/
+{@3`).find(c=>(y-=c)<1542)&3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYpNa8JAEEDv2h8xBprMkI82E0WkrpReC0LxKIIh2bUR2ZVxLSz98em2557eg/fO7Vd762S4@tK6Xo9GjUFtuG748e1ujBY8Tvlpkj98vzZHqsxge@zUBkOpOlrXizlT2ozGCQooKOsCQuSKly9R1gr4mTlqntMEQGCm4G80GIggTaFz9uYuurq4E4bKu52XwZ6Qqmvb73wrHudUgPxbOJYEE8hhn33ctbZZAdl7nH651YP/1JId9nKIR0IJjT8)

#### How?

The ASCII codes of the data string are:

```javascript
[ 11, 50, 47, 10, 43, 12, 123, 64, 51 ]
```

They represent the number of years to be added to get the exclusive upper bound of the next interval, starting at \$1542\$.

Once the correct interval has been identified, we apply the following formula to its encoding number \$N\$ to figure out whether it was a King, a Queen or neither:

$$(2132 \bmod N)\bmod 4$$

The last interval is not explicitly encoded. For any input greater than \$1952\$, `find()` returns `undefined` which is turned into `NaN`. But because we use a bitwise AND with \$3\$ rather than an actual modulo \$4\$, it is eventually coerced to \$0\$ -- the expected result for Queen Elizabeth II.

| N | Exclusive upper bound | Interval | 2132 mod N | and 3 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 1553 | 927 - 1552 | 9 | 1 | King |
| 50 | 1603 | 1553 - 1602 | 32 | 0 | Queen |
| 47 | 1650 | 1603 - 1649 | 17 | 1 | King |
| 10 | 1660 | 1650 - 1659 | 2 | 2 | Neither |
| 43 | 1703 | 1660 - 1702 | 25 | 1 | King |
| 12 | 1715 | 1703 - 1714 | 8 | 0 | Queen |
| 123 | 1838 | 1715 - 1837 | 41 | 1 | King |
| 64 | 1902 | 1838 - 1901 | 20 | 0 | Queen |
| 51 | 1953 | 1902 - 1952 | 41 | 1 | King |
| undefined | n/a | 1953 - ... | NaN | 0 | Queen |

Comment: When does this imply the monarch will change next?

Comment: @Simd Once we reach \$N>1952\$, the output does not change anymore. So this code is not doing any prediction about future monarchs.

Comment: That's sad, but understandable.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 60 bytes

A function that returns `0` for **King**, `1` for **Queen**, and `2` for **Neither**.

```python
lambda n:sum(c>n-ord('ؑٱڦޟܭ'[c%5])>0for c in b'2@I')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BTsMwFET3KYf4G2RbtZHt1GldKRVbzhAi5KYEIjVOlKRSOQYnYMeOBbcBhLhK8I/UdmON/sybcfsyPDc@Hsv0fty7ertz4Nf9oabFxoum21Hy9fr9@fP@9/b7QbLi2uRsI8umgwIqD1uiZ7Or2zvCRgcpZFkO6D2g1zn/9Ei11DHLozMhueJ6HU2xHg@Vbw8DZTd9u68GSjgQFmzYc@hCY@1aWvmBQ38KCMJY8JE/Xmam@BzUxILLjjnMUyh4NC37S9DqJYfpUyFZlVBSz8A3AyZc5nPk2y5MhvsYwkIZE3NQiYyFShYWZSKFWkod5FIthFrFoVJZqYSyRk/tWuATISsQRWplg7QLpKQWiAYZWIEoFpgTlZgwkBj7Dw)

Comment: Ooh this looks clever!

Answer (score 8):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2.0-alpha), 78 bytes

```
O I|>927=xP?GxF3'165'0I|&<1553x<1603x|&<1702x<1714x|&<1837x<1901x&<1952x<2022x
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/v2#WyJPIEl8PjkyNz14UD9HeEYzJzE2NScwSXwmPDE1NTN4PDE2MDN4fCY8MTcwMng8MTcxNHh8JjwxODM3eDwxOTAxeCY8MTk1Mng8MjAyMngiLCIzIl0=)

Nothing special, just check for ranges with `<` and `>`. Since we have to output just three distinct things, `0` is for when it's neither, `true` for a queen and `false` for a king. Slightly unminified:

```
O I|>927=xP?GxF3'165'0
  I|&<1553x<1603x
   |&<1702x<1714x
   |&<1837x<1901x
    &<1952x<2022x
```

Comment: A Knight of the realm.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/),  <s>58</s>  57 bytes

```python
lambda y:9%(6-sum((y:=y-v)<1500for v in b'61/\n+|?4'))%2
```

(Contains an unprintable byte between `+` and `|`.)

An unnamed function that accepts an integer from \$[927,2022]\$ and:

- produces a `ZeroDivisionError` for years when neither a king nor queen reigned;
- returns \$0\$ if a king was on the throne during the year (except Charles III (2022)); or
- returns \$1\$ otherwise (when a queen was on the throne the entire year, or 2022)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDNTsMwEITv5SW2h8q2SEOSQqERERfoBQmJK20PbrppLbVOtHEirNJnD06g4Wcv9o6/mdW6sGaX68ldQU2WLJu9PKw3Emw8G/HpuKwOnNs4seNa3Ic3QZDlBDUoDWs2Da@W@vLi4@GaCTGKmoKwVnlVQgKMDVrQtiBJvUU@i249iIJoIuIBuDJkvy5tkbNk3IpekGWJZJzu/DzwIBQeZGwu1X4I8zYYJcHRniCrdGpU7qagqUjjBo50Yl0OvqdYGHhDyh9VrUpHPRHl9Hds1HVpRYTauH7BnpXeMo@9VojanS@ozA6JrRa06liV9fgwgfPSP6kFKW249c6U@PfCfN9nv8X@174NzSc)**

#### How?

The byte-string `b'61/\n+|?4'` encodes the integers `[54,49,47,10,43,11,124,63,52]`. The `for` loop subtracts each from the year, `y`, cumulatively by employing the walrus operator, `:=`, and counts, with `sum(...)`, how many are less than `1500` (\$54\$ years before the first lone queen). To force an error for the sixth period (no monarch) and two distinct values otherwise arithmetic is employed:

| years | sum=N | 6-N | 9 mod (6-N) | (9 mod (6-N)) mod 2 | identifies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 927-1553 | 9 | -3 | 0 | 0 | king |
| 1554-1602 | 8 | -2 | -1 | 1 | queen |
| 1603-1649 | 7 | -1 | 0 | 0 | king |
| 1650-1659 | 6 | 0 | err | err | none |
| 1660-1702 | 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | king |
| 1703-1713 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 | queen |
| 1714-1837 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 | king |
| 1738-1900 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 1 | queen |
| 1901-1953 | 1 | 5 | 4 | 0 | king |
| 1954-2022 | 0 | 6 | 3 | 1 | queen |

---

### Non-erroring alternative, 57 bytes

```python
lambda y:2**sum((y:=y-v)<1500for v in b'61/\n+|?4')%40%3
```

Returns \$2\$ for King, \$1\$ for Queen, or \$0\$ for neither.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9Pb8IwDMXv7EuYA3LCsi5NYX@qVbvtMmnSzsChQAqRIK3ctFLE@Oxd2g00zRfLz79nPVfe7UubPFXUFdmyO@TH9TYHn6rptG6OjPk083ctf4nnUhYlQQvGwhof4vulvb35ep0hn8zkJOkq0q0pmxoyQBz1qO9Ryu1Os2f1KEBJlfB0BKEoUAXzfBjyutbkghZwJkUsFBdQ4FtuDuNAnfyZA2nXkNVbONEZB9emIdLWhUML/NDG7TWhwM9Gaxv6u7E7XC1oNbCmuOLjDC5Jf6L0VZGxjnlxofi/DUZRhH/F66u/hu4b)

#### How?

Same sum as before with different arithmetic:

| years | sum=N | 2**N | (2**N) mod 40 | ((2**N) mod 40) mod 3 | identifies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 927-1553 | 9 | 512 | 32 | 2 | king |
| 1554-1602 | 8 | 256 | 16 | 1 | queen |
| 1603-1649 | 7 | 128 | 8 | 2 | king |
| 1650-1659 | 6 | 64 | 24 | 0 | none |
| 1660-1702 | 5 | 32 | 32 | 2 | king |
| 1703-1713 | 4 | 16 | 16 | 1 | queen |
| 1714-1837 | 3 | 8 | 8 | 2 | king |
| 1738-1900 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 1 | queen |
| 1901-1953 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | king |
| 1954-2022 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | queen |

Comment: Is erroring acceptable?

Comment: It says "any three distinguishable outputs", so I don't see why not.

Comment: @Seggan I've added a non-erroring alternative that ties.

Comment: The non-erroring version is great.

Answer (score 5):

## x86-64 machine code, <del>38</del> <del>32</del> 31 bytes

```
48 B9 64 12 33 20 9F A1 52 B8 31 C0 99 B6 06 88 EA 48 C1 C1 07 14 04 29 D7 99 79 F3 24 05 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLbjtowEH22v2JKhdZmwyqEAFsI/YO@9KkPSJWxncRVcGguNKjsr5eOnbDb7q6U2DMnZ87cIqeZlNfrR2Nl0SoNSd0oUz7kn@l/UGH2r7HK2Mxh1NgGUuZOwTdwKo0CbZUslWZ8Q0V9AAZfR4w@ZEW5FwWkNF1TcihPUMkugNljkjzCBRZhkszwjpdJsnDADIGFR6IkiWOHoDFfeSNGK0RriUY0d@EzDF9S0pUVaIG6eFAi1c8@lcoDWNJKH7VohuyqCEDmlFRl0VeyokQoCQLxmJK63YNWBoXUTeiHraGXQKZVnrlAAd3QoeM15SPArv1QDsLYfi5VJl0uUcFkgs6J09@UuC8dbCEM4OyuTQ8Vom6c283ngXe@142omoGRYnvMRX2KVhsMT7YQhdEczft7TgnKEpN6Rv8BLhdgTj5lHefwYeslkempnvuSw8GEHHGzTcpG49hM8V3D2Ozs6N9aAuimsx7AXjFkqPn87DzX3DnoibrnpruzX4TMjdXgJzZyEq2tTWa1GoZ0xEj2CuMp8n7lptDAjq6RN4RhBxxumWAcRt@w8skRh7N5qQDY2MD@3Oia@87ckjiKTt9Jyn1g2zif3e3snfNx421l3UKe6PX6R6aFyOrr9LCM8cA/fouCuvgL)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes the year number in EDI and returns a value in EAX: 4 for kings, 0 for queens, and 1 for the interregnum.

In assembly:

```
f:
    mov rcx, 18<<8 | 50<<1 | 46<<58 | 10<<51 | 42<<44 | 12<<37 | 124<<30 | 64<<23 | 51<<16
                    # Put this constant in RCX.
    xor eax, eax    # Set EAX to 0.
    cdq             # Set EDX to 0 by sign-extending EAX.
    mov dh, 6       # Set the second-lowest byte of EDX to 6.
repeat:
    mov dl, ch      # Set the low byte of EDX to the second-lowest byte of RCX.
    rol rcx, 7      # Rotate RCX left by 7 bits.
    adc al, 4       # Add 4+CF to AL.
    sub edi, edx    # Subtract EDX from EDI.
    cdq             # Set EDX to 0 by sign-extending EAX.
    jns repeat      # Jump back to repeat if the subtraction's result is nonnegative.
    and al, 5       # Keep only the 1s bit and the 4s bit of AL.
    ret             # Return.
```

The basic way this works is to decrease the given number by 1554, 50, 46, 10, 42, 12, 124, 64, 51, 137, stopping when the result is negative, so that the loop executes a different number of times for each period of constant output.

The years of change were assigned to make all the period lengths even, except the last two. This allows the values to be stored in 7 bits each, so that nine can fit into a 64-bit register, while extracting 8 bits at a time (which includes the previous value's low bit) and still functioning correctly.

The 10th value extracted (for Elizabeth II's reign) entirely overlaps the 1st and 9th values, so we can only control its high bit, by assigning the year 1952. But because only years up to 2022 have to be handled, it is OK for this value to be higher than necessary.

The 1st value, which is 1554, is created by setting the second-lowest byte before the loop and then inserting the low byte within the loop (saving 2 bytes compared to pre-setting the whole thing).

To handle the interregnum, notice that the low bit of RCX ends up being 1 only when the given year is during the interregnum or the king period that follows it, and that is the same bit that gets copied into CF by the `ROL` instruction. An `ADC` instruction adds 4+CF to AL with each iteration, so that the 4s bit alternates between 0 and 1, while the 1s bit stays 0 initially, then becomes 1 for the interregnum and becomes 0 again for the next period, and stays 0 thereafter. At the end, an `AND` instruction picks out those two bits.

Comment: Awesome! Not that I understand it fully.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>118</s> 117 bytes

```
165.
LP
155[4-9]|15[6-9].|160[0-2]|170[3-9]|171[0-3]|183[89]|18[4-9].|1900|195[3-9]|19[4-9].|20[01].|202[01]
Q
...+
K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lcw5DsJADAXQ3ldBseyZeJYzkAJqK0UKChoKRJm7D/6jNM/W9/J9/d6fYwwtxrQ9SM18Xfp@qnmJyqcWcVlSJFU8z1HVSHI0LXtD0OZN7HaRwK69fsUpPuisCQ09iZlvdB@jWyUVoCCBDFZgoIAKGoiLPw) Link includes some test cases. Outputs `K` if there was ever a King in that year, otherwise `Q` if there was ever a Queen in that year, otherwise `LP`, as the Cromwells used the title "Lord Protector" for some of that period. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @pxeger.

Comment: I think `....?` can be shortened to `...+`, and, if you make the output for Oliver Cromwell one character only, just `..+`

Comment: @pxeger It's not just Oliver!

Comment: @graffe You know what I mean!

Comment: @pxeger yes of course

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>25 23</s>  22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁽£4;“1/½+¿|?4‘Ä<⁸SḂ⁻¡3
```

A monadic Link that accepts an integer in \$[927,2022]\$ and yields:

- \$0\$ if there was a king on the throne at any point during the year (except for Charles III (2022));
- \$3\$ if neither a king nor queen reigned; or
- \$1\$ otherwise (if a queen and only a queen reigned all year or Charles III succeeded (2022)).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9qZWxsef//4oG9wqM0O@KAnDEvwr0rwr98PzTigJjDhDzigbhT4biC4oG7wqEz////MTY1MA)** Or see [all years](https://tio.run/##AUYAuf9qZWxsef//4oG9wqM0O@KAnDEvwr0rwr98PzTigJjDhDzigbhT4biC4oG7wqEz/yzDhylH//9yYW5nZSg5MjcsIDIwMjMp).

#### How?

```
⁽£4;“1/½+¿|?4‘Ä<⁸SḂ⁻¡3 - Link: integer, Y
⁽£4                    - 1553
    “1/½+¿|?4E‘        - code-page indices = [49,47,10,43,11,124,63,52]
   ;                   - concatenate -> [1553,49,47,10,43,11,124,63,52]
              Ä        - accumulate -> [1553,1602,1649,1659,1702,1713,1837,1900,1952]
               <⁸      - less than Y? (vectorises)
                 S     - sum -> S
                    ¡  - repeat...
                   ⁻ 3 - ...number of times: not equal to three
                                             (leave as 3 when no monarch)
                  Ḃ    - ...action: mod 2
                                    -> 0 if a king during the year except 2022; or
                                       1 otherwise
```

Comment: Very happy to have a Jelly answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-Mutf8 -MList::Util=pairgrep -p`, 67 bytes

```perl
$_=/^165/?N:pairgrep{$a<$_&&$_<$b}unpack"U*","ؑكڙڞڦڲܭݭޠߦ"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lY/ztDMVN/ez6ogMbMovSi1oFol0UYlXk1NJd5GJam2NK8gMTlbKVRLSUfpxsSbzbdm3pp3a9mtTXfW3l17b8H9ZUr//xsZGJn8yy8oyczPK/6v62uqZ2BoAKRLS9IsgJRPZnGJlVVoSWaOLcyG/7oFOQA)

Outputs `1` for a Queen, `0` for a King, or `N` for none.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 67 bytes

```bash
>$1<165?&&bye 2
< (1(<553-603>|6<89-94>|7<2-14>|<837-901>)|<1952->)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwe5i20BvP660_CIFQwWNaksjcz09IwMjo1rNao2lpSVpuhY3ne1UDG0MzUzt1dSSKlMVjLhsFDQMNWxMTY11zQyM7WrMbCwsdS1N7GrMbYx0DYG0jYWxua6lgaGdZo2NoaWpka6dJtQoXU01O_2U1DL9vNKcHGsbGxsVQz09vRgFleJoe23DWOuiXAWt2prSvMxCBd00Q4imRdGxCyAsAA)

Outputs via exit code: 0 for queen, 1 for king, and 2 for neither.

Explanation:

- `>$1`: create a file named according to the input
- `<165?`: search for a file beginning with `165` (as there was no monarch during that decade)

  - `&&bye 2`: if one exists, exit early with exit code 2
- `<`: otherwise, search for a file matching the long pattern of periods when there was a queen

  - `<x-y>` is a Zsh pattern searching for a number in the range \$ [x, y] \$
- Zsh will then exit with 1 if no file matches that pattern, and 0 otherwise

Comment: Very impressive!

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 59 bytes

```c
*p;f(y){for(p=L"2/\n+{@3,//";y>1552;)y-=*p++;y=2704%*p&3;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU9NS8QwEL0Xf8QYWEmalu5mXRaJEe@K4NnuocS0W9BasvGjlP5146RRVxxImHnz3rwZnTdae5/2sqYDG@sXS3t1S0RRdvxkvF5nRUHkcLXabIRkQ67SnnM5KLFdni/S/mwtJ992Dp6rtqMsGRPA0PvKpuDMh3vYgYIRyE3bNSQDcv9qTBeSO9O6vbEEJjlLwozemjek56sI4SpAAz6YyiJ@IbYy5pcKxFKIWHHOZnq0/plljUMJnoQMJo@tGuhsc6oChf02juoQ35sgQ/7DcXZNyeKxdPM7lOGaYJIFdhaPxmz3x3RK4j8l/lPXT1Vz8Pn7Fw)

-2 bytes thanks to ceilingcat!!

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 131 bytes

```python
a=[1553,1603,1689,1694,1702,1714,1837,1901,1952,2022]
f=lambda x:"AKQ"[any(i for i in range(5)if a[2*i]<x<a[2*i+1])*2or x//10!=165]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYuxDoIwFEV3vuLJ1GIT@ooFSmBwdnJuOtRotYkWQhzK19ficnJucs@yfV9zaFKyk0YpG4Yt39GrDHVi2HGRgdn6pmOoOGZIwQQXwhRuetvP7W4hDuX5ci21DRvx4OYVPPgAqw3PB5HUO7BaVN6McfzLEQ2tRL7FukZ@mLCVJu1Z3DOdJzJAhZyB4MjNUMCy@vAljkRK0w8)

Comment: 93: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclBDoIwEEDRPacYd6A1zLS2wISehLCo0cYmWghhUWI8e4Xd/3nztr6mqHJ29qu1Yo3CtB1r0aBkkqJVDZub6LTkBn@Ft2/3uT8cJHZxK0OfrvRUfbi4IYx@WiBAiOCqs9w71TXhyZLR@aB00LAfCaCOUIBEwpELmJcQ19KXqaryHw "Python 3 – Try It Online"). (Outputs with `False`/`True`/`2` instead of `A`/`K`/`Q`, as there's no reason to use meaningful formats)

Comment: @pxeger Maybe that should be a separate answer?

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 120 bytes

```python
r=lambda s,l:{*range(s,s+l)}
f=lambda y:2*(y in r(1650,10))+(y in r(1553,51)|r(1689,6)|r(1702,13)|r(1837,65)|r(1952,71))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3LDoIwEEX3fEWXHZhFH5mWkvgxNYqS1EoKm0b99gpNMO7OfeTeOa/3Z9SlpFPwj/PFswXD8GqTj7crX3DpAnya8QjzoFqe2RRZ4tKQQCkAup9DpJEkvPewd2gqWaFQ6oq9tmiooiOFVgKUOU1x5SN3ygI0h9qn/uX2tXW/)

Interpreting the output: 0 = King, 1 = Queen, 2 = Neither.

Nothing too fancy here. Commented version of `f`:

```python
f=lambda y:(
  2

  # y in r(1650,10) = is neither king nor queen
  * (y in r(1650,10))

  # y in ... = is queen
  + (y in r(1553,51)|r(1689,6)|r(1702,13)|r(1837,65)|r(1952,71))
)
```

Comment: You could save 3 bytes by switching to Python 2 where `range` results in a list and so you can just concatenate them together.